# Add 48 Hours to MySQL Datetime using PHP and print it in Javascript Date format

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, date

I have a datetime stored into database like this

```
2013-02-22 00:00:00
```

What I want to do is using PHP, it should count this date + 48 Hours and then print a message like this

```
Sat Feb 23 2013 09:38:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Which is actually a default return value javascript Date() function. So that I can pass it to the countdown timer plugin I am using.

Any suggestion how can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us some code?

Comment: I have already tried adding 48 Hours using MySQL select Query like this -- SELECT gift_date, DATE_ADD( gift_date, INTERVAL 48 HOUR ) AS remaining_time
FROM  `gift_mst`

Comment: So, add that in the question. So what you want is to use that value in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try:

```
$dayAfterTomrrow = strtotime("2013-02-22 00:00:00")+172800;
echo date("r", $dayAfterTomorrow);
```

.. which will give you a format you can pass to a javascript date object.

But you don't even have to pass in a formatted date to the "new Date()" instantiator in javascript - you can also pass in a timestamp (unix epoch) in milliseconds. So the second line of my example isn't even necessary if you just take the stamp of $dayAfterTomorrow and multiply it by 1000 in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use [date()](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [mktime()](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) together to find dates in the future or the past.